# Open attachment from mail using ios 8 app [swift]

Tags: swift, email, email-attachments, ios-app-extension, uti

In my app, I designed a new encrypted type data as attachment to the mail. When I receive the same type of attachment(filename.filetype) from another user, I want the attachment from mail to open in my app. I went through the action extensions tutorials. But, what is missing is, how can I open that particular type of attachment using my swift app. I get the answers in Obj-C as well as the previous versions of iOS.  I am seeking an answer in iOS8, Swift to handle the file.

Here is my info.plist

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>pvt file</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.pryvateBeta.pvt</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>pvt</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDocumentsType</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>pvt file</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pryvateBeta.pvt</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Here is my AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL Url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    let encrypteddata = NSData(contentsOfURL: Url)

    return true}
```

Comment: I could not solve this Obj-C. I am seeking  a reference or answer in Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to declare the file type your app will handle in your apps `Info.plist`.

For instance the configuration shown below declares that the app is able to open `.lumenconfig` files which are basically XML. [See this for more info about the declarations.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html)

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <!-- The name of this file type. -->
        <string>Lumen Configuration</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <!-- The name of this file type. -->
        <array/>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <!-- The different type identifiers that are handled 
             as this type of file. -->
        <array>
            <!-- This is a custom type I declare below -->
            <string>at.zujab.lumen.lumenconfig</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

If you use a custom type like I do in the above example you also need to declare that type. [See this for more information about declaring your own type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html)

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <!-- How these files are structured -->
        <array>
            <string>public.xml</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <!-- This is the identifier for the custom type -->
        <string>at.zujab.lumen.lumenconfig</string> 
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <!-- How your app calls these files. -->
        <string>Lumen Configuration File</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
             <!-- The extension of the files of this type -->
            <string>lumenconfig</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Then in your app delegate implement a handler to handle the file:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    //....

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        //url contains a URL to the file your app shall open

        //In my EXAMPLE I would want to read the file as a dictionary
        let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfURL: url)

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this the info.plist of the action Extension?

Comment: @MohammedJanish No. You do not need an extension to open files in your app. This is the Info.plist of the app itself.

Comment: <array>
            <string>public.xml</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <!-- This is the identifier for the custom type -->
        <string>at.zujab.lumen.lumenconfig</string> 
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <!-- How your app calls these files. -->
        <string>Lumen Configuration File</string> What does these lines stand for?

Comment: What is the url to be given in the AppDelegate? Is it the url of the mail App?

Comment: @MohammedJanish There I declare my own type. I’m using a custom type called `lumenconfig` which iOS does not know. The URL, of course, points to the file (when you tap the email attachment and choose open in).

Comment: How can I get that url? And how can we set the action for the file which is downloaded

Comment: Are you unable to read Swift? `url` contains the URL.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. There are no errors, but still i can't open the attachment. I referred some more tutorials. I think my info.plist is okay. Can't find the bug

Comment: @MohammedJanish Without seeing your plist I also won’t – the chance are higher if you add your plist into your question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31915406/edit) it.

Comment: @MohammedJanish This picture is pretty useless, please select the first row, hit cmd+c and cmd+v it into your question **and remove all redundant information not related to your problem**. But what I can see is that you have no values for "Conforms to UTI".

Comment: What should I do to handle that file in view controller??

Comment: @MohammedJanish You’ll somehow need to push a view controller into your navigation controller.

Comment: I have already six view controllers in my project. i want to open the file in one of these.

Comment: Even though I need some more steps to complete this, You did ur part and i'm ticking ur answer. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting an NSData file from mail. Where should i mention this in plist. @idmean

Comment: @MohammedJanish You do not have to declare the files structure if it does not conform to any known structure. So if it is a custom binary format you don't need to do anything.

Comment: i got the solution. Ur help is appreciated.