# associate file types with iOS application in swift

Tags: ios, swift, email-attachments, uti

I am new to iOS development. I designed a custom attachment to send through mail. When I receive the attachment in mail, I want to open the attachment in my app.
Here is my info.plist

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>pvt file</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.pryvateBeta.crypt.pvt</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>pvt</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDocumentsType</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>pvt file</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pryvateBeta.crypt.pvt</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And here is my Appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL Url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    let encrypteddata = NSData(contentsOfURL: Url)
    

    return true
}
```

I have asked the question before in this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915406/open-attachment-from-mail-using-ios-8-app-swift). It was a possible duplicate of this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application). But, I didn't get the solution and could not find where the problem is.

What is missing in my code? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use the Info tab of the app target editor to set up your document types and exported UTIs. It will set up the Info.plist properly.

Comment: Is there anything missing in the plist? So that i could add it in the way you mentioned @matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this. i copy and pasted ur code in my plist and its not working. then i created another plist and its code is as below. and its working

```
       <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.pryvateBeta.crypt.pvt</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>pvt file</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.pryvateBeta.crypt.pvt</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/pry</string>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>pvt</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no changes yet @Shebin

Comment: What does the <LSItemContentTypes> really contains? Should it be the Bundle ID + file extension?

Comment: It really works.. I would like to know one more thing. How can I handle this file?

Comment: I want  to open this in one of my veiwcontrollers.

Comment: As you mentioned in ur question. that delegate will invoke.. the parameter url contain ur file (path)

Comment: It is an encrypted document.

Comment: @MohammedJanish you know how to present details from a file that already in ur phone local document directory?

Comment: @MohammedJanish if yes, then u just convert the url to normal path by Url.path!

Comment: Of course, But how can i take the obtained url from AppDelegate  to my view controller?. @Shebin

Comment: @MohammedJanish is that viewController is ur first page? u use navigation bar or tab bar?

Comment: Not the first one. I use navigation controller

Comment: @MohammedJanish ok..good.. u have to create "var detail :DateToBePassedToThisViewController?" //appdelegate

Comment: "detail?.functionCallFromAppDelegate(Url.path!)"//paste in that delegate(method) in ur question

Comment: in the page u use to display " extension DateToBePassedToThisViewController {
    func functionCallFromAppDelegate (filePath: NSString)
    {
        NSLog("path %@", filePath)
//here u do ur stuff
    }
}"

Comment: I  got another way. I just declared a global variable to store the path, and it's working fine. I was struggling on this issue and now it's fine. Ur help is really appreciated.